# Extjs 4.2: How to apply base64 encoding and decoding on a particular grid column

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need to apply base64 encoding on one of the Grid column before submitting it to backend and then I have to decode it as well.

I tried something like this:

In my store, before sync:

```
beforesync: function(options, eOpts ){
    // Encode string
    options.create[0].data.ColumnText = btoa(options.create[0].data.ColumnText);
}
```

In my model's change method, I did this:

```
{
    name: 'ColumnText',
    type: 'string',
    convert: function (value, records) {

        // Decoding Encoded Information
        return atob(value);
    }
}
```

Problem occurs when I try to add new record using Row Editor plugin, as soon as I create a new record and try to POST(submit button) it, The new record data is validated by model and when it reaches this line:

```
return atob(value);
```

It throws an error that value is not encoded properly which is right as it is a newly created object and I am encoding data in before sync method of my store.

Can anyone tell me How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solution for this, which I used once was to make use of the **record** object which you are receiving in the **convert** method of the model.

You can look for typeof "record.raw". For the stored/fetched records it will be a string containing entire xml data string. For newly created records, which you are creating via Row Editor, typeof "record.raw" will be an object(your data model object).
Something like this:

```
{
    name: 'COM_BLOG_Text',
    type: 'string',
    convert: function (value, records) {

        if(typeof records.raw.ColumnText == "undefined")
            // This means that it is an encoded stored record
            return atob(value);
        else
            // this means that it is a temporary/newly created object
            return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. This is exactly what i was looking for.